# How to use the random method with a parameter not with a fixed integer?

Tags: java, android, random

I know that the random() method is used with a fixed integer that I should determine. However my need is to use the same function with a parameter, I mean an integer that I haven't now but it will be determined during the runtime.
here's my code:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random r1 = new Random();
            num1 = r1.nextInt(z);

            if (num1 < z) {             
                 //do something

            } else {

                //do other thing
            }

        }
    });
```

z is the parameter it determined during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you want to happen here. Do you want to generate a random number along a range defined at runtime? Or do you want to dynamically seed the RNG?

**Case range defined at runtime:**

Your current code should work. Here's the documentation:

```
nextInt(int n)
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.
```

**Case dynamic seed:**

Construct the Random object with z as so:

```
Random r1 = new Random( z );
```

Also, where is the z value coming from?

Comment: I tried your second solution 'Random r1 = new Random(z);' but it is showing an IllegalArgumentException.  z a count of a database elements which is an unknown number, at the runtime it will count the number of element  (questions) in the specified column and will show a question rundomly. the user  can add questions to the database so i can not know how much questions that's why I'm using a parameter.

Comment: Ah. Then try initialise your RNG with seed time then use nextInt( z ) to randomly select a question from your list of questions. What data type is z?

Answer (score 0):

out of javaDoc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

public int nextInt(int bound)

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All bound possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

your

```
if (num1 < z)
```

will never ever reay the else because it will be true in evry singel run.
z is just giving the upper limit of your random value but exclusive so it can never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand your question. I assume you want a random z value at run time.
If that is the case, then:

```
    int z = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 100);
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int num1 = r1.nextInt(z);
```

It will generate a random z number from 0 to 99.

Comment: z is a not a random value. z  is a count of a database elements which is an unknown number, at the runtime it will count the number of element (questions) in the specified column and will show a question rundomly. the user can add questions to the database so i can not know how much questions that's why I'm using a parameter.